# SonicWall WAN to LAN connection

Tags: nat, sonicwall

Please note that I'm an absolute novice with all things network related, so please be patient with how basic this question probably is. We have a SonicWall TZ600, which I am trying to configure NAT policies for based off of the policies we already have configured in our iptables on our Linux box. The iptable reads:

`-A PREROUTING -p tcp -d [public IP] -i eth2 --dport 90 -j DNAT --to-destination [private IP]:90`

I believe this is defined in layman's terms as "when a TCP connection is made to [public IP] port 90, reroute to [private IP] port 90."

My issue is that I cannot figure out how to make my access rule and NAT policy work. The access rule goes from WAN to LAN with a source as the [public IP], destination as [private IP], and service as our port 90 service. The NAT policy takes any source input, original destination as [public IP], translated destination as [private IP], and services set to our port 90 service object.

When I am logged onto a machine that is not on the network and browse to [public IP]:90, nothing loads. I've read through the logs, but nothing seems to stick out to me (probably because I'm a novice). Any ideas?

Comment: Not for nothing, but is there a process/service listening on port 90 on the destination host?

Comment: @joeqwerty yes, there is. While I'm on the network, I can connect to the private IP on port 90.